# Installing XDebug 64bit on windows

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

I am trying to install XDebug. I am using Windows7 of 64 BIT. My PHP version is 5.6.3 (got this using phpinfo();). I placed below xdebug file in **ext** folder inside **php** folder (I renamed the file as php_xdebug.dll).

[image]

I placed below code in php.ini file and restarted apache.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\XAMPP\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\XAMPP\tmp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

But I **could not** see the below section while I was trying to see using `phpinfo();`

[image]

Could anyone say where is the problem?

Comment: There is no 64 bit windows PHP version, try to use 32 bit

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123. It is working in 32bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you messed 2 things up:

1. If your computer has 32/64 bit
2. And if your PHP version is a 32/64 bit version

So since you are on windows there is no stable 64 bit PHP version *yet*, as you can see [here](http://windows.php.net/):

[image]

Also to test this you can do a little trick and run this code:

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

output:

```
9223372036854775807  //64bit
2147483647           //32bit
```

So download the 32 bit xdebug version and everything should work fine.

Comment: Now I am facing **Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)**. Could you help me in this regard ?? Thanks

Comment: @abuabu I normally don't use netbeans, so I can't really help here. Just make sure the settings in the IDE and php.ini file matches. + After each change in your ini file you need to restart your server.

Comment: Thanks - I have a 64-bit machine, but my PHP 7.3 is 32-bit!

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
zend_extension="W:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0beta1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"
```

`[XDebug]
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "W:\php"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"`